# jQuery/CSS3 - constantly 3d flip 5 divs?

Tags: jquery, css, 3d, flip

I have around 10 divs which have to constantly flip with a delay of 3 seconds for each div

The last effect from this codrops link is what I am looking for, but without having to click a div

http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/

I have tried my luck with jquery, but this one seems to be a bit more complicated for a beginner.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxxQLx

```
 <button class="btn btn-8 btn-8g">3D Button</button>

$('.btn').click( function () {
  $(this).addClass('btn-error3d');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [CSS3 Animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)